# Django query stock price a year ago

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to find the ticker prices which are greater than the price on the same day a year ago. How do I run the django query to get those prices?

```py
from django.db import models


class Ticker(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class TickerPrice(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(
        Ticker, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ticker_prices"
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    close_date = models.DateField()
```

I'd like to run the query like below, but couldn't figure out how to get the ticker_price_a_year_ago.

```py
TickerPrice.objects.filter(price__gte=ticker_price_a_year_ago).
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using subqueries, something like this:

```py
import datetime
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Subquery


last_year = datetime.datetime.utcnow().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)

last_year_ticker_price_subquery = TickerPrice.objects.filter(
    ticker=OuterRef('ticker'), 
    close_date__date=last_year,
).order_by('-close_date')

TickerPrice.objects.annotate(
    last_year_ticker_price=Subquery(last_year_ticker_price_subquery.values("price")[:1])
).filter(
    price__gte=F("last_year_ticker_price"),
)
```